# How to Stream local file modifications in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was looking for a way where I could listen to changes performed to a file. For example, there is a file say 'x.json' where I will read and write on this file.

I will write data like, write['key']['c'] = 3 //just for representation purposes.

```
{
   "key":{
      "a":1,
      "b":2,
      "c":3
   }
}
```

since 'c':3 has been added to 'key', I want that to reflect in my app. ie: read

My Code:

```
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File xfile = File('${directory.path}/x.json');
    _fileSubscription = xfile.watch().listen((FileSystemEvent event) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          currentXFileContent= jsonDecode(xfile.readAsStringSync());
          print('Within stream, currentXFileContent: $currentXFileContent');
        });
      }
    });
```

I get this message

> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: File system watching is not supported on this platform, path = ''

How can I solve this?

Comment: Sadly this seems that it is not supported on IOS and Android [watch documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/watch.html).There's this [watcher package](https://pub.dev/packages/watcher) that I couldn't get to work myself yet.
My actual workaround is to have a callback to call anew my reading function after each call of the writing function.